# Every radical ideal in a Noetherian ring is a finite intersection of primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Prove that if $I$ is a radical ideal and $ab\in I$, then $I=\operatorname{rad}(I+(a))\cap \operatorname{rad}(I+(b))$.

> Deduce that every radical ideal in a Noetherian ring is a finite intersection of primes.

I've done the first part (showing the sets are equal), but don't know how to do the second.

Comment: As an additional note, every radical ideal is the intersection of the primes minimal over it. But in a Noetherian ring, there are always only finitely many primes minimal over a given ideal.

Comment: Is Noetherian needed? Seems like one can use Zorn's lemma to get that a radical ideal is a finite intersection of primes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $I$ is a radical ideal which is not prime, then there are elements $a,b$ with $ab \in I$ but $a \notin I$ and $b \notin I$. By the first part you can write $I$ as an intersection of two radical ideals $I_1, I_2$ containing $a$ and $b$ respectively. The same procedure can be applied for $I_1$ and $I_2$, and since the ring is Noetherian you will reach prime ideals after finitely many steps (otherwise there would be an infinite ascending chain of (radical) ideals).

Comment: I'm curious if others agree with me, but I don't think the parenthetical part is that obvious.  Just because each chain of ideals is finite, how do you know this entire procedure terminates after finitely many steps?  I think it's equivalent to saying that in a binary tree, if each branch is finite, then the tree is finite.  I agree it's true but I think at least in a formal class setting it requires careful proof.

Comment: For others who may be wondering how to get around the snag @CJD brought up, the argument can be completed as follows: Since the ring is Noetherian, there would necessarily exist a radical ideal maximal with respect to the property of not being equal to the intersection of finitely many primes. Then $\sqrt{I+(a)}$ and $\sqrt{I+(b)}$ would both be the intersection of finitely many primes, which is a contradiction.